# Realm field not found exception

Tags: android, realm

I am trying to implement Realm into a project of mine. I keep running into this

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid query: field '_id' not found in class 'messages'.
```

Note: `MESSAGE.COLUMN_ID = "_id"`

### Query

[image: Query]

The Logcat prints `true` for hasField.

### Model

[image]

The same thing works for other tables fine.

Comment: other tables names have '_' underscore symbol?

Answer (score 1):

Typed Realm queries use the **field name** as the argument, and are mapped over internally to the internal schema field name.

Therefore, your query ought to look like this:

```
MessageDto messageDto = realmInstance.where(MessageDto.class)
                              .equalTo("mLocalId", query.getMessageId())
                              .findFirst();
```

Comment: This was it for me. Really wish the docs would have mentioned this